# The event on backbone view is not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have written Backbone view - ListView and want to display table in to it. For individual table rows, there is another view - EmployeeView.

I am binding click event on delete button which is inside template with function-deleteEmployee(), but looks like event is not working and function is not called.

Here is the code block-

```
            app.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

                tagName : 'table',

                render : function() {

                    $(this.el).append("<tr><td>Employee</td><td>Designation</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>");
                    app._collection.each(this.renderEmployee, this);
                    $('#main').append(this.$el.html());
                    // main is the main div tag inside body

                },

                renderEmployee : function(model) {

                    var employeeView = new app.EmployeeView({
                        model : model
                    });

                    $(this.el).append(employeeView.render().el);

                },

                initialize : function() {

                    app._collection.on('reset', this.render, this);

                    app._collection.fetch();
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(app._collection));

                }
            });


            app.EmployeeView = Backbone.View.extend({

                tagName : 'tr',

                template : _.template($("#employee-template").html()),

                events : {

                    "click input#editemp" : 'editEmployee',
                    "click input#deleteemp" : 'deleteEmployee'

                },

                render : function() {

                    console.log('inside employeeView');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model));
                    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                    this.delegateEvents();
                    return this;

                },


                editEmployee : function() {

                },

                deleteEmployee : function() {

                    alert('Hello');

                }

            });
```

Here is the template-

```
    <script type="text/template" id="employee-template" >

        <td><%= name %></td>
        <td><%= designation %></td>
        <td><input id="editemp" type="button" value="Edit"/></td>
        <td><input id="deleteemp" type="button" value="Delete"/></td>

    </script>
```

Comment: See it working here..http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/2yqrh1yx/

Comment: Since the events are bound to the `tr` element..can you check if your template is being wrapped by `tr`?

Comment: Thanks for the input Sandeep but tr element is not there in the template code as its already declared as tagName in EmployeeView. I am suspecting, issue is the way I am adding EmployeeView into main view ListView

Comment: Don't use ID's for things appearing more than once on your page, or really ever

Answer (score 0):

Use a class to identify the repeatable elements instead of ids (because an id identifies a single unique element).

```
events : {
  "click .editemp" : 'editEmployee',
  "click .deleteemp" : 'deleteEmployee'
}

 <script type="text/template" id="employee-template" >
    <td><%= name %></td>
    <td><%= designation %></td>
    <td><input class="editemp" type="button" value="Edit"/></td>
    <td><input class="deleteemp" type="button" value="Delete"/></td>
 </script>
```

updated JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/2yqrh1yx/11/